# Passing a table from one lua state to another

Tags: c++, lua, lua-table

I have two lua states, say L1 and L2, and I have a complex table (table containing other tables, or strings and numbers) in L1. I want to pass this table to L2 through C++. Is there any easy way to do this other than explicitly opening the entire table in C++ and then sending  the entries one by one to L2.

The table is something like this :

```
Property = 
{
    Name = "Ekans",
    Stats = 
    {
        HP = 300,
        Attack = 50,
        Defense = 30,
        SpAttack = 20,
        SpDefense = 30,
        Speed = 60
    },
    Attributes = 
    {
        LOS = 5;
        Range = 1.5;
        MoveDelay = 0;
    },
    Alignment = 
    {
        Name = { -6, -10},
        Health = { -6, -7}
    }
}
```

I tried using this code to do this :

```
static void transferTable(lua_State *L1, lua_State *L2)
{
    lua_pushnil(L1);
    while (lua_next(L1, -2) != 0)
    {
        if (lua_isnumber(L1, -1))
        {
            cout << lua_tostring(L1, -2) << " : " << lua_tonumber(L1, -1) << endl;
            lua_pushstring(L2, lua_tostring(L1, -2));
            lua_pushnumber(L2, lua_tonumber(L1, -1));
            lua_settable(L2, -3);
        }
        else if (lua_isstring(L1, -1))
        {
            cout << lua_tostring(L1, -2) << " : " << lua_tostring(L1, -1) << endl;
            lua_pushstring(L2, lua_tostring(L1, -2));
            lua_pushstring(L2, lua_tostring(L1, -1));
            lua_settable(L2, -3);           
        }               
        else if (lua_istable(L1, -1))
        {
            cout << lua_tostring(L1, -2) << endl;
            lua_pushstring(L2, lua_tostring(L1, -2));
            lua_newtable(L2);
            transferTable(L1, L2);
            lua_settable(L2, -3);
        }
        lua_pop(L1, 1);
    }
}

static int luaStats(lua_State* L)
{
    //Exchanging tables from "entity->getLuaState()" to "L"
    lua_getglobal(entity->getLuaState(), "Property");

    lua_newtable(L);
    transferTable(entity->getLuaState(), L);

    lua_pop(entity->getLuaState(), 1);
    return 1;
}
```

The code works but gives an error when trying to copy the two tables in Alignment table. If I change the alignment table to

```
Alignment = 
{
    Name = { x = -6, y = -10},
    Health = { x = -6, y = -7}
}
```

it works, but when I remove x and y to store them at index 1 and 2, it gives error. Can anyone give a solution to this?

Comment: Are you sure that's the print function you want to use? Aren't your Lua-numbers potentially floating point?

Comment: No, I don't intend to print basically. My main objective is to send the complete table. When I searched the net, I found that a general function to read any kind of values in a table can be implemented like this. But I am not getting how to use these values and create a table of them using C++ and then pass it on to another LUA State.

Comment: Your problem is a general (de-)serialization problem. I guess the only kind of Lua data you want to transport are strings, numbers, and tables which are only referred to once. So, serialize into a native buffer, deserialize however often you want. Google for `pickle` for a Lua way to serialize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't detecting the type of the key used, and assuming that it is a string. `lua_tostring` converts the numerical keys into strings in your new table.

So this:

```
{"foo", "bar", "baz"}
```

Becomes this:

```
{["1"]="foo", ["2"]="bar", ["3"]="baz"}
```

You need to check for numerical keys (or other key types) as well.

Also, when pushing many things onto the stack, be sure you have enough stack space by using the [`lua_checkstack` function](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_checkstack). Lua gives you 20 by default, but if you have deeper tables, you may exceed this limit and trigger undefined behavior.